# ¿Cómo lanzar la app en Android Wear desde la versión mobile en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-wear, google-play-services

Algunas apps que incorporan una versión para `Android-wear` des de la  versión `mobile` abren la versión de `Android-wear`

¿Cómo se puede realizar un lanzador de la app de mobile a wear?

Comment: En Android Wear documents hay un tuto muy bien detallado http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, se debe realizar a través de las `Google Play Services`

Se debe enviar un mensaje donde en el wear se procesa si coincide con un patrón en este caso `/messageapi/launcher` lanzará la actividad des de un servicio de escucha.

Para simplificar el proceso usar la libreria [ConnectionUtils](https://github.com/Fleker/android-boilerplate/blob/master/mobile/java/com/felkertech/n/boilerplate/ConnectionUtils.java)

### Parte mobile

importar las google play services solo la parte de Android Wear

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'`

Añadir a la Acvididad `implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Wearable.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume: ");
    super.onResume();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause: ");
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected() called with: bundle = [" + bundle + "]");
    WearConnectUtils.sendLaunchCommand(mGoogleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("GoogleApi", "onConnectionSuspended: " + i);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w("GoogleApi", "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

### Parte wear

Crear un servicio de escucha `WearDataLayerListenerService`

```
public class WearDataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    private String TAG = WearDataLayerListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/messageapi/launcher";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);

        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(START_ACTIVITY_PATH)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Asignar el servicio al `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".WearDataLayerListenerService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/LaunchApp" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Ups esto es útil para mi! =0 gracias por el aporte!